# How to put arguments onto setAttribute function in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, css

I have some function like below, that sets ***inline*** css attribute to the elements. It's kinda very simplified JQuery's .css() method:

```
function cssSetAttr(styleName, value) {
   for (var i = 0, n = someObject.length; i < n; i++) {
        someObject[i].setAttribute('style', [styleName][value]);
}
someObject.cssSetAttr('color', 'red');
```

Problem is how to put arguments into setAttribute like this:

```
setAttribute('style', 'styleName: value')
```

Comment: use display.style

Comment: I'd suggest creating a different function for styling properties. Then you can call it like this: `setCSS('propertyName', 'value')` and use this internally within the function: `element.style[propertyName]`. This has the benefit that you can call it multiple times on the same element without overwriting any previous values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
setAttribute('style', `${styleName}: ${value}`);
```